# What do I need to "fix" for a case property highlighted yellow with a exclamation point warning?

Tags: commcare

I have a module which modifies case_type household_member.
There are three forms, in two of them `#case/resident_name` is shown in the left hand menu and upper blue banner as "resident_name" in a gray box (as expected) however in one of them, the same code `#case/resident_name` is highlighted in yellow rather than gray and prefixed with an "alert triangle."

Of note, in all three forms, the standard gray box appears in the actual form-builder window (e.g. in the display text and display condition boxes).

Since this is an active project and case_property issues could affect a LOT of data, I just want to make sure this "yellow warning" isn't something I need to make a priority fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The yellow warning box means that CommCare hasn't detected that your application has saved that case property before. It should still reference the case property when you deploy your application so if the property exists in the case everything will work correctly. It should also have the same behavior in all forms in your application.

Some helpful debugging tips would be:

- check that you've spelled the property name correctly
- check that all forms are modifying the same case type